# Can you specify qualifier and delimiter characters when exporting from Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Can you specify qualifier and delimiter characters when exporting from Google Docs?

Right now, when I go to a spreadsheet and do *File » Download As*, it downloads something that is comma delimited and has no qualifier.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot specify the qualifier, but you have a choice of delimiter: comma or tab.

If you download as CSV, you get a comma-delimited file. If you download as text, you get a tab-delimited file.

Answer (score 5):

My solution for this was to

1. Download as `.ods` (for Open Office)
2. Open in Open Office Calc
3. Click *File* → **Save As**
4. There you can specify you want CSV format
5. Last dialog lets you select the delimiter you want to use

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022-10-28, if you are downloading manually, you can specify different formats (csv, tsv, ...)

[image]

If you are publishing (making public / sharing) the document, you will get a link like

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/.../pub?gid=1...5&single=true&output=csv
```

If you change `csv` for `tsv` you get a `tsv` file.

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/.../pub?gid=1...5&single=true&output=tsv
```

Same for `html`.

I don't know any other way to **specify** the kind of output / delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any option for delimiting on Google Docs other than selecting the cell(s) containing the data and:

*Data -> Split Text To Columns*

There should be a small dropdown menu that pops up to specify the delimiter. However I think if you are uploading a CSV, it automatically separates the data (as much as it can) using commas.

Select *Split Text To Columns* from the Data Menu:
[image]
Delimiter Selector:

[image: image2]

Comment: I think you're answering how to Import or Split data INTO Google Sheets (or alongside existing sheets).  The question is about exporting from Google Sheets into a text file.  Though your answer was insightful on its own, it doesn't answer this question.